# How to create two sequences without relying on side effects?

Tags: c#, sequence

Suppose you have to process a sequence of `InputType` that produces two sequences one of type `OutputType` and the other of type `ErrorType`.

A basic implementation could be:

```
class SeqProcessor {
  private IEnumerable<ErrorType> errorTypes;

  public SeqProcessor()
  {
    this.errorTypes = Enumerable.Empty<ErrorType>;
  }

  public IEnumerable<ErrorType> Errors
  {
    get { return this.errors; } 
  }

  public IEnumerable<OutputType> ProcessItems(IEnumerable<InputType> inputTypes)
  {
     yield return new OutputType();
     if (err) this.errorTypes = this.errorTypes.Concat(new ErrorType());
     yield return new OutputType();
     yield return new OutputType();
     if (err) this.errorTypes = this.errorTypes.Concat(new ErrorType());
     // ...
     yield break;
  }
}
```

I see these two alternatives for example:

- Use a common interface (eg. `IProduct`) between `OutputType` and `ErrorType` and let `ProcessItems` return `IEnumerable<IProduct>` (than discriminate using Linq).
- Define a subclass of `ErrorType` called `NoError` and let `ProcessItems` return tuples `IEnumerable<Tuple<OutputType, ErrorType>>` (if no error, `NoError` will be used in the tuple).

**Edit:**

Since `ErrorType` are semantically different from `OutputType`, mixing these types could be a violation of *Single Responsibility Principle*.
Can the use of a delegate be an acceptable alternative design:

```
class SeqProcessor {
  public IEnumerable<OutputType> ProcessItems(
    IEnumerable<InputType> inputTypes,
    Action<ErrorType> onError)
  {
    yield return new OutputType();
    // ...
    onError(new ErrorType());
  }
}
```

Which approach do you use in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, I see multiple possible solutions here:

1. Stay with the original implementation (where I would replace `private IEnumerable<ErrorType> errorTypes` but something that allows you to determine the item the error belongs to). In this context, the *errors* you are encountering would have the significance of a **warning** (which is why I would also prefer the name `Warning`) because they are separated from the actual result.
2. Using a common interface for both result types (that is, output and error) would only make sense if other functions consuming the resulting list could really make use of the error output. I doubt that this is what you intended but imho, this would be valid design choice.
3. As Pieter pointed out, having a sub-class `NoError` of `ErrorType` would really be nasty. **However**, a nicer solution would be using `ResultType` as a base for the types `NoError` and `Error`. That way, you really have *specialization* of the base class. Still, I wonder that the output will contain in case of an error. The original element? A processed, but invalid element? Null? Depending on what you want to achieve, this *could* be reasonable, but this is hard to tell from the given information and, to be honest, I doubt that is what you want.
4. The `OnError` is good practice in many contexts because it allows for great flexibility. However, you will still have to think about what will be the corresponding entry in the result in such a case. Imho, it will probably be the best choice to simply leave it out in order to avoid the treatment of either `null` or either special values.

All in all, it seems like the `OnError` approach seems to be most promising, even though additional information may drive you towards one of the other mentioned approaches.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Meanwhile my experiments are demonstrating the greater flexibility of built-in delegates. Appreciated also the reasoning about proper naming with such few informations. You talked of `Warning` because you see that the process is not stopped, nevertheless they are true `Error` (the process goes on to capture them all). About `null` (expect for few guard clause in most cases in ctor) I do the possible to treat them in different way; see the already quoted __Null Object Pattern__ and the [MayBe Monad](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/04/TheBCLalreadyhasaMaybemonad/).

Comment: and the about the use of BCL delegates, for reference I want to add this [article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces/) which states that the are preferable instead of one-method interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach suggests that a NoError instance is a specialization of a NoError; this would rarely be true in practice. More likely the shared functionality between the two is small, making the first approach better.

Comment: you mean a specialization of ErrorType? I've thought of as a variation of the Null Object Pattern, using NoError instead of `null`.

Comment: I'm trying to not treating null, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: For the second comment the point is just a clarification of what you asked. The point of the main question is the question itself and you suggested the first choice, so I'm back to the evaluation step (taking into account your suggestion).