# Constructor Injection, properly couple two class that operates on sequences

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've two class that produce sequences of types that implements `IFoo`.

```
interface IBar {} // the starting type
interface IFoo {} // this can undergo various transformations

class SeqProcessor1 {
  IEnumerable<IFoo> Process(IEnumerable<IBar> input1) {
    //...
  }
}
```

and

```
class SeqProcessor2 {
  IEnumerable<IFoo> Process(IEnumerable<IFoo> input2) {
    //...
  }
}
```

`SeqProcessor2` transforms an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` to another `IEnumerable<IFoo>` so In the code you'll see:

```
var seqProc1 = new SeqProcessor1();
var seqOfFoo = seqProc1.Process(seqOfBar);

var seqProc2 = new SeqProcessor2();
var finalSeqOfFoo = seqProc2.Process(seqOfFoo);
```

**Since there's no other usage pattern in the application, could be a correct design choice use constructor injection to make the relationship between two types explicit?**

Follows an example in which to simplify testing an *header interface* (see [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions/)) is extracted from `SeqProcessor1`:

```
interface ISeqProcessor1 {
  IEnumerable<IFoo> Process(IEnumerable<IBar> input1);
}

class SeqProcessor2 {

  ISeqProcessor1 proc1;

  SeqProcessor2(ISeqProcessor1 proc1) {
    this.proc1 = proc1;
  }

  IEnumerable<IFoo> Process(IEnumerable<IBar> seqOfBar) {
    var input = this.proc1.Process(seqOfBar);
    //
    return input;
  }
}
```

See how `SeqProcessor2::Process` is changed to accept `IEnumerable<IBar>` needed to its dependency.

Leading to this usage:

```
var seqProc2 = new SeqProcessor2(new SeqProcessor1());
var finalSeqOfFoo = seqProc2.Process(seqOfBar);
```

**Edit:**

- The key here is that the first processor (the one that needs `IBar`) transfroms `IBar` instances to `IFoo` instances.
- Even if both `SeqProcessorX` have a similar signature `SeqProcessor1` can't be *naturally* chained with `SeqProcessor2` without forced changes.
- Other processor with the same signature of `SeqProcessor2` (`IFoo` -> `IFoo`) could be instead chained.

Comment: This looks like a classic case for `Decorator` pattern.

Comment: @Davin Tryon, this implies you opt for making dependency explicit with  ctor injection?

Comment: Yes, but I would also create a common interface `IProcessor` for all processors.  Then you can chain them in any sequence.

Comment: @Davin Tryon, the first process IEnumerable<IBar>. This could introduce a common marker interface (e.g. `ICommon`) and for what I remember this is discouraged in .NETFX Library Design Guildelines.

Comment: @DavinTryon but +1 for the idea of chaining processors.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify the given code a bit? In the current form, it is imho not valid since the second processor expects IEnumerable<IBar> whereas you supply IEnumerable<IFoo>. Are IFoo and IBar the same thing in the actual implementation?

Comment: @bigge, I've edited the question. Should be more clear, if not, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read your edits, I would say that yes, this is a valid/reasonable structure for your use case. You see me a bit careful with the formulation because there might not be enough information to judge the matter to full extent. On the other hand, it is probably not possible to discuss all possibilities here which is why I've added this as an answer despite the doubts.

Nevertheless, I added this (positive) answer since
- you remark that this is the only usage pattern. Thus, We should only have to consider the present code
- the structure makes the intent of what you want to achieve very clear. From reading, I can directly understand that you need a specific processor
- the code is short, simple and free of code duplications

To make a long story short: Yes, I would consider this a valid use of constructor injection

Comment: +1 and this answer, it's clear that without the full context is hard to reply. I always try to abstract a bit my questions for easy of asking and for letting other user benefit of it. To complete the picture I can quote another my question (related to that) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380262/how-to-create-two-sequences-without-relying-on-side-effects) that for the moment lacks a _marked reply_. Maybe it could be of some interest for you.

Comment: Well, there is no doubt that abstracting questions is a good idea, so no need regretting anything :) Thank you for the appreciation and also for the link. I've also posted an answer to the referenced question.